# disabling systemUi alert in Android rooted phone

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I'm wondering how can I disable the "unable to charge your device" alert in a Samsung note 2 .
The alert occurred when I connect my to mhl cable .. The micro USB have 6 pins.
I can do any manipulation .

Comment: And why you want to do that?

Comment: I want to connect my note 2 to my TV permanently . when I plug the mhl cable in . the battery indicator start blinking and every minute an error message pop up and it's very annoying. So I want to disable it. My phone is rooted